# JLabel doesn't show image

Tags: java, image, jlabel

I'm not sure where the problem is. Is it in the path? The image doesn't show although there are no errors at all in the code syntax. Should I provide the whole path or just place the image in the directory and call its name? Thank you.

```
public class NetworkingGame {

private JFrame jfrm;

NetworkingGame(){
    jfrm = new JFrame("Angry Painters");
    jfrm.setSize(800, 480);
    jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jfrm.setVisible(true);

}// end of constructor

public void ImageLoading(){
    ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/TOSHIBA/Documents/NetBeansProjects/NetworkingGame/build/classes/angry-painters.jpeg");
    JLabel jl = new JLabel(i);
    jfrm.add(jl);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run(){

            NetworkingGame ng = new NetworkingGame();
            ng.ImageLoading();
        } // end of run method
    }); // end of Runnable

   }//end of main method
}//end of class NetworkingGame
```

Comment: Is there image in that path?

Comment: @PradeepSimha yes, `angry-painters.jpeg` is the image :)

Comment: Try this: `ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon(new URL("C:/Users/TOSHIBA/Documents/NetBeansProjects/NetworkingGame/build/classes/angry-painters.jpeg"));` it will throw an exception if the file does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use path something like this :

```
jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("c:\\Users\\xyz\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\game\\src\\images.jpg"));
```

**Update**

If dis also does not work, then

```
    jLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/image.jpg")));
    jLabel.setText("jLabel");
```

should.The `image.jpg` should be inside your project folder.

Comment: I don't think it is because of the separator. "the forward-slash works on all systems" says the document.

Comment: Yeah, true, but if the path is ok,and having an image too, worth giving a shot

Answer (score 3):

Do not use the file path as icon location as this will only work on your computer. You really cannot expect all machines in the world to have C:/Users/TOSHIBA ...angry-painters.jpeg in the right place!

Copy the file next to the source code (.java) class you use and then call

```
 new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("angry-painters.jpeg"));
```

The builder should copy the image resource to the class folder itself.

Comment: still not working, I moved the file to where you mentioned and changed the code!

Comment: Yes `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: This exception means the image cannot be found so getResource returns null. If it is really in that folder, stupid to ask but could you check the spelling of the file name?

Comment: I did. They're the same (that wasn't stupid, it may have been the fatal error of mine. thanks). I placed the file with the source code, isn't this where it should be?

Comment: Last thing, check if the builder is copying it to the class folder along the compiled classes. If it does not, you need to go through your IDE settings to make it to do so. Should copy by default.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code doesn't like the way your binding the image.

assumes that your put the images/icons in the source folder

```
ImageIcon i=new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("myimage.jpeg"))
```

or if you create a folder in the source folder

```
InputStream stream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/images/image.jpg");
BufferedImage bufferedImage=ImageIO.read(stream);
ImageIcon icon= new ImageIcon(bufferedImage);
```

Comment: is the code you mentioned instead of `ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("path/of/image.jpeg");`?

Comment: @InspiringProgramming yeah.

Comment: ImageIcon i =new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("myimage.jpeg"))

Comment: How will I add this `InputStream stream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/images/image.jpg");` to the JLabel then?

Comment: BufferedImage bufferedImage=ImageIO.read(stream);
 ImageIcon icon= new ImageIcon(bufferedImage);

Answer (score 0):

**in IntellijIdea. 2021**
In my case it just didn't read image files.
To fix that:

**1.** make res folder in project root('src's folder sibling)

**2.** Handle artifact in File->Project Structure->artifacts by  + , -

**3. File->Project Structure->artifacts->output layout tab** make structure of final jar as 'res' folder , app root package folder(say 'com'), and 'META-INF'  folder. Fill out them with content from yourapp/output folder and 'res's content from mentioned in **1.** step  'res'.

**4.** After that in 'project structure' 'Modules' rightclick on 'res' and mark it as resources.

**5.** Declare images like this:

`ImageIcon loadingLcl = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/res/32.gif"));`
before putting into JLabel.

Also it s preferable to read image once when initializing the app. Otherwise sometimes it can throw IOException. So if possible handle that at start. Like they do in gamemaking.